# Install Exaile music player 4.0.0 in Solus Linux

Tags: software-installation, music-player, solus

Posted in order to provide an answer.

---

Exaile is a multi-tabbed music player that can access music as collection and as folder structure. It is actively developed, a new 4.0.0 beta version is out there,  but not available in Solus Linux repos.

How to install it?

Answer (score 0):

[Download](https://www.exaile.org) the source files[.](https://www.exaile.org)

Unpack the archive and - opening a terminal in the resulting folder:

```
make
sudo su
make install
```

To get a launcher available:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/exaile.desktop
```

and paste this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Exaile Music Player
Icon=exaile
Categories=System;Settings;
Exec=sh -c "/usr/local/bin/exaile"
```

Make it executable (`chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/exaile.desktop`) or trust it when prompted by Nautilus file manager.

---

Tested this in Solus 3.999, without the [problems encountered in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018579/47206). `python-dbus` was already installed, `python-gi-cairo` was not needed.